# ThymeLeaf with Grails 2.4

Tags: grails, thymeleaf

Is it possible to use ThymeLeaf with Grails 2.4?

There is a plugin that was started (https://grails.org/plugins/pending/250), but it doesn't appear to be active anymore and it noted some significant issues.

I've done quite a bit of searching and haven't been able to find anything on this subject other than the abandoned plugin... maybe I should take that as a sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it out and see. Clone the repo, then edit `ThymeleafGrailsPlugin.groovy` and change the version to a -SNAPSHOT version:

```
def version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Then run `grails compile` and `grails maven-install`. That second script will build the plugin and copy it to your local Maven cache in the same format as if it were retrieved as a published plugin.

To use it in a project, add it like any released plugin, e.g.

```
compile ':thymeleaf:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

and it will resolve from your Maven cache.

To make changes, leave the version but run `clean` and `maven-install` again, but delete the plugin directory in the cache. That'll be something like `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/thymeleaf/0.1-SNAPSHOT` - delete the whole directory, and after rebuilding the new version will be used.

David's email is in `ThymeleafGrailsPlugin.groovy` if you get stuck. It's easy to miss comments in the plugin proposal pages, so don't take a lack of a reply there as an indication that the plugin is totally abandoned.

Comment: Thanks Burt. Knowing that the pulgin is currently the best option for ThymeLeaf with Grails answers my question. I'm also evaluating Spring Boot which may be a better fit for what I need since ThymeLeaf support is built-in.